# Replacing the default camera in electron for all browser views

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

There is a task - to change cameras in all browser views when changing the camera in the browser view. Now I correctly determine the cameras and forward the necessary deviceIds to the browser view.

The problem is that in this case it changes only when shown to the user himself, but if you call someone via video link, then a standard webcam will remain.

I see two solutions:

Change default media device before loading browser view
Remove all unnecessary media devices so that only 1 device remains.
I couldn't find either solution. Please help me :)

Replacing the default camera in electron for all browser views

render:

```js
const [devices, setDevices] = useState([])
  const [currentDevice, setCurrentDevice] = useState({audio: '', video: ''})

  const initDevices = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
      .then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices())
      .then((deviceInfo) => {
        setDevices(deviceInfo.map(item => ({
          kind: item.kind,
          label: item.label,
          deviceId: item.deviceId
        })))
      }).catch(console.error)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initDevices()
  }, [])

  const onChangeHandler = ({e, type}) => {
    setCurrentDevice((prev) => ({...prev, [type]: e.target.value}))
    electron.setMediaDevices(e.target.value)
  }
```

main.js

```js
for (const item in browserViewList) {
    if (!browserViewList[item]) continue
    browserViewList[item].forEach((item) => {
      item.browserView.webContents.send(events.setMediaDevices, params)
    })
  }
```

preload.js

```js
ipcRenderer.on(events.setMediaDevices, (e, device) => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devicesInfo) => {
    const audio = devicesInfo.find(item => item.label === device)?.deviceId
    const video = devicesInfo.find(item => item.label === device)?.deviceId

    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {deviceId: audio ? {exact: audio} : undefined},
      video: {deviceId: video ? {exact: video} : undefined}
    })
  }).then(stream => {
    const video = document.querySelector('#video_video')
    if (!video) return

    video.srcObject = stream
    video.play()
  }).catch(console.error)
})
```

I tried to remove devices through select-hid-device, but all in vain.